# How to lazy-load a React "widget"?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

My terminology is probably wrong here, but I don't know what to call it other than a "widget" when you don't have a whole React app, but are attaching little React pieces to different `root`s on an otherwise static HTML page. But, that's what I'm doing:

```
const StripeForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Stripeform'));
// ...
const formPlaceholder = document.getElementById('cwr-stripe-form');
const formRoot = createRoot(formPlaceholder);
formRoot.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StripeForm />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is, I want to lazy-load my `StripeForm`, so that it doesn't load until needed (and therefor maybe never at all).

I have the `React.lazy` `import` and my `webpack` bundle working fine. The issue is "until needed".

As I understand it, lazy-loaded components load when they begin rendering, which I suppose is usually when they move into the viewport. And I equally suppose that "usually" is overridden by the fact that I'm calling `.render`, which I guess causes it to render immediately.

Those guesses might be wrong, but the fact is, when I load my web page, the supposedly lazy-loaded component is loaded, even if it's not in the viewport.

How to I get these sort of "widgets" (there are several others on the page) to load lazily (i.e., to attach to my `root` placeholder element, but not actually load and render until necessary)?

Comment: `lazy` tells React that the component doesn't have to be loaded on the initial render, but it's still getting rendered because you're calling `render` immediately. How do you know when you want to render this root?

Comment: The earliest I'd want to load it is user interaction with the page, and the latest I'd want to load it is when it's in the viewport. I'd be happy with whatever React's normal behavior would be, if I weren't calling `render`.

Comment: React's normal behavior is to render the entire component tree into your root(s). Is there a reason you need to delay loading this? Is it not shown by default? Is it slow to load? Is it expensive?

Comment: It's not shown until several "screens" down on the page, either on mobile or desktop, and it's very slow to load (the Stripe iframe can take a full second to download, and another 1/2 second to render — sometimes longer on low-end mobile devices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using `lazy`, so React will only import the component if it's not being rendered. The problem is that you're still rendering the component by default, so the component is still being loaded once it's available.

React is declarative, so the way to solve this is to conditionally render the component only when you want it to be rendered. You can implement this by using a visibility library such as [react-is-visible](https://github.com/lessp/react-is-visible), for example:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useIsVisible } from 'react-is-visible'

function LazyStripeForm() {
  const ref = useRef()
  const isVisible = useIsVisible(ref, { once: true })

  return <div ref={ref}>{isVisible && <StripeForm />}</div>
}
```

Now you can render `LazyStripeForm` instead of `StripeForm` and it should do what you want.

Also, if `StripeForm` has a lot of dependencies, you should ensure your build tool is code splitting the file so that it's not increasing the size of your main bundle unnecessarily.